# How Tomcat connectors work?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, connector

Say you use a (blocking) BIO connector like this:

`<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxConnections="1000" maxThreads="200" />`

and you make 201 concurrent connections, what happens to the last connection?

If you make 1001 concurrent connections then what happens to the last connection?

Next let's use a (non-blocking) NIO connector `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`

Will there be any differences if we make 201 and 1001 concurrent connections?

As far as I understand there is no behavioural differences between NIO and NIO2, only the implementation differs, is this true?

What connector Tomcat 8 uses with default protocol settings `protocol="HTTP/1.1"` when no APR/native connector is available?

------------- edit ---------------

I made a small servlet like this:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
response.getWriter().write("ok");
```

Set these settings `connectionTimeout="20000"` `maxConnections="10"` `maxThreads="2"` and made 50 concurrent requests. All would be accepted and then executed 2 at a time (as executing threads finished). Non of the requests timed out or got errors even though `connectionTimeout="20000"` and `maxConnections="10"`.

Exactly the same for both `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"` and `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"`. I guess the difference shows when you have `Keep-Alive` connections. BIO would block a thread for entire duration of connection, NIO would free up the thread after every request.

When I tested the same scenario but with added parameter `acceptCount="15"` as  Dennis R pointed out, only then most requests returned `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused`.

---------- edit2 -----------

Note that if I set this `maxConnections="100"` `acceptCount="15"` then all 50 connections were accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are configuration parameters: [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html)
There is basically Executor and the queue default length in standard implementation is:
acceptCount=100

Max connections is how many connections are accepted in total(in queue and being processed ).
Connections are rejected, I assume based on whatever reached first.

NIO  is not limited by request-processor threads.

Here is good [summary/comparison](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/TomcatConnectorsEU_0.pdf)

Comment: The link to the summary/comparison on the linuxfoundation site is broken.